# Find the size of a data which i am sending to webservice

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

Is there any way to find the size of a data which i am sending to webservice from the client in Csharp dotnet

Comment: what webservice are you communicating with? asmx, wcf, rest, custom, ...? how does your call look like

Comment: RepWS Test= new RepWS();
Test.Url = "<Some url/test.asmx";
Test.Webmethod(XMLDocument);

Comment: so you are working with a visual-studio-created-proxy of your .asmx-webservice? or what does your direct call to the url look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to find the size of your data when it's serialized to XML, which is what happens when you call a standard SOAP webservice:

```
var data = GetMyData();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType())
using(var stream = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
    var sizeOfData = stream.Length;
}
```

Comment: -1 for not placing the `MemoryStream` into a `using` block. I'll remove the downvote if you'll fix that.

Comment: @John Saunders I added that using block a year ago, please remove the downvote. Thanks in advance!